# pointer data member not initialized

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to implement a binary search tree class.
This is the code (header):

```
template <typename Data>
class BST
{
public:
    BST();
    void Insert(Data _item);
    //~BST(); TODO

    struct Node
    {
        Node()
        {m_left = m_right = 0;}

        Data m_data;
        Node* m_left;
        Node* m_right;
    };

    Node* m_root;

private:
    void RecInsert(Node* _root, Data _item);
    Node* CreateNode(Data _item);
};


template <typename Data>
BST<Data>::BST()
: m_root(0)
{
}


template <typename Data>
void BST<Data>::Insert(Data _item)
{
    RecInsert(m_root, _item);
}

template <typename Data>
void BST<Data>::RecInsert(Node* _root, Data _item)
{
    if (NULL == _root)
    {
        _root = CreateNode(_item);
        return;
    }
    if(_item < _root->m_data)
    {
        RecInsert(_root->m_left, _item);
    }
    else
    {
        RecInsert(_root->m_right, _item);
    }
}

template <typename Data>
typename BST<Data>::Node* BST<Data>::CreateNode(Data _item)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->m_data = _item;
    newNode->m_left = newNode->m_right = 0;
    return newNode;
}
```

So basically my class holds Node* which initialized to null in the constructors and each time I insert an element, a new node is allocated. But it seems like I am doing something wrong. This is my test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    BST<int> tree;
    tree.Insert(4);
    tree.Insert(11);
    tree.Insert(1);

    cout << tree.m_root->m_data << "\t"; //segmentation fault!!
    cout << tree.m_root->m_left->m_data << "\t";
    cout << tree.m_root->m_right->m_data << "\t";
}
```

I get a segmentation fault (see comment in the code for location).
While debugging I see that each time I call the insert function the m_root data member is NULL, although after the the first insert it is not supposed to be null. so something in my insert is not correct.

Thanks

Comment: The only place you assign to `m_root` is in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> While debugging I see that each time I call the insert function the m_root data member is NULL, although after the the first insert it is not supposed to be null. so something in my insert is not correct.

The first argument of `RecInsert` needs to be a reference to a `Node*`. Otherwise, any changes to `_root` in the function is only a local change.

Declaration

```
void RecInsert(Node*& _root, Data _item);
               //  ^^^
```

Definition

```
template <typename Data>
void BST<Data>::RecInsert(Node*& _root, Data _item)
                          //  ^^^
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu so if I understand correctly, in C i would pass a Node** in order to do the change? And here I need to pass a reference? Thanks

Comment: one more question. In the destructor I will call a recursive function to deallocate all nodes. The function is           void BST<Data>::FreeNodes(Node* _root)    in this case should I also pass a reference to the pointer? Since here I am only dealing with the pointer itself and not what it points to, I assume I can pass a pointer? Thanks